# Intercepting filter/sort/column "model" changes / transactions

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I would like to control the grid's sorting, filtering, and column states with an external store. Ideally I want to intercept the filterChanged and sortChanged events, emit them to the store, and let the store update the grid programmatically using the grid API.

```
readonly GRID_CONFIG: GridOptions = {
    onSortChanged: (event: SortChangedEvent) => {
      // Tell store that the sort changed
      this.sortChanged.emit(this.grid.api.getSortModel());
    },
    onFilterChanged: (event: FilterChangedEvent) => {
      // Tell store that the filter changed
      this.filterChanged.emit(this.grid.api.getFilterModel());
    },
    onFilterModified: (event: FilterModifiedEvent) => {
      // This isn't useful because it only relates to the floating filters pre-apply...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, once the onFilterChanged and onSortChanged events are called, the grid has already been updated, so the updates from the store are redundant.

The closest thing to what I want is `isApplyServerSideTransaction`, as this callback allows cancelling the transaction.

```
    isApplyServerSideTransaction: (params: IsApplyServerSideTransactionParams) => {
      // Emit model changes to the store so that the store can update the grid
      this.sortChanged.emit(this.grid.api.getSortModel());
      this.filterChanged.emit(this.grid.api.getFilterModel());

      // Do not update the grid (redundant)
      return false;
    }
```

However, this is only supported for Server Side Row Model Full mode. This callback is never fired in my case, since I am using partial mode.

Are there any other tricks for hooking into the model changes before they're applied, or is this just not supported?

Update: I'm specifically trying to intercept the UI-triggered changes to the sort/filter model. I know this can be achieved with custom filters (and maybe custom headers?) but I'd much rather leverage Ag-Grid's built-in UI than build a whole custom copy, just to intercept one event.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Server-side Row Model, the getRows callback is fired whenever the Grid is requesting data, i.e. whenever you filter/sort/group etc. So if you want to intercept what is being returned to the Grid, you should do it inside the getRows callback.

Comment: My problem is that getRows is called for both UI-triggered changes and API changes, and there's no way to distinguish between the two at that point. I was hoping to intercept the UI changes and only let API changes through. So perhaps that's a different problem entirely...

Answer (score 0):

It may be a late response, but it might help someone.
**isApplyServerSideTransaction(params)** get triggered only when **applyServersideTransaction() api is triggered for add/update/delete rows from grid**.